# Scrape text from PubMed find_element_by_css_selector VS visibility_of_all_elements_located

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get abstract from an article in PubMed.  If I go directly to the article link with my following code, then I can get the abstract that I want.

[image]

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="../drivers/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6268174/")
time.sleep(randint(1, 5))
abstract = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#ABS1 p").text
```

However, I have a list of articles containing more than a thousand articles to get their abstracts.  So I made an automate script as follows

```
import time
from random import randint
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Define article name, i.e. Artificial intelligence in radiology
name = "Artificial intelligence in radiology"

# Invoke Chrome and go to PubMed website
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="../drivers/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov")
print("Accessing " + driver.title)
print(driver.current_url)

# Enter research article
time.sleep(randint(1, 5))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='search']").send_keys(name)

# Click search
time.sleep(randint(1, 5))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[class='usa-search-submit-text']").click()

# Click on the article link
time.sleep(randint(1, 5))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class='docsum-title']").click()

# Click to navigate to full text
time.sleep(randint(1, 5))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[data-ga-action='PMC']").click()

# Get abstract
time.sleep(randint(1, 5))
abstract =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#ABS1 p")))
```

I use the same tag `div#ABS1 p` as the previous code but it does not work and raised time out exception.  May I have your suggestions what make this difference results and how to fix it?

Comment: Why not use the official API? It's more comfortable and faster
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/research/pubtator-api/publications/export/biocjson?pmcids=PMC6268174

Comment: Is that allow to get full text?

Comment: For fulltexts, see this API: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/research/bionlp/RESTful/pmcoa.cgi/BioC_xml/PMC6268174/unicode

Comment: Oh great.  Did you use Entrezpy?  Does it require email authentication?

Comment: You could just use the `requests` library, as far as I know you don't need to register, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/research/bionlp/APIs/

Answer (score 0):

It depends for what line it raises the timeout exception?

But in any case, replace the 'time.sleep' lines with explicit waits:

```
# Enter research article
inputWait = EC.element_to_be_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='search']")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(inputWait)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='search']").send_keys(name)

# Click search
spanWait = EC.element_to_be_located(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[class='usa-search-submit-text']")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(spanWait)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[class='usa-search-submit-text']").click()
```

..etc

Typically, I prefer to use xpath over CSS selectors. Also, you could probably do this using requests and beautifulsoup instead of selenium.